CSV Download not working within Views Bulk Operation's Action extension function
I am not getting any errors in the logs, and the CSV doesn't seem to download. I am trying to get the selected data from Views Bulk Operations into a csv that downloads upon the associated selected data with the Action extension that I am making:
I tried the VBO Export module, and the same thing happens.
EDIT: took out dots indicating that there were more rows so there isn't any confusion that that is what was in my code.
    public function executeMultiple(array $objects) {
    
        $tempFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'download_csv_');
        $out = fopen($tempFile, 'wb');
        if ($out) {
          fputcsv($out, array('Company Name'));
          foreach ($objects as $entity) {
    
            $company_name = $entity->getTitle() ?? 'Test';
            
            fputcsv($out, array($company_name));
          }
          fclose($out);
    
          $headers = new ResponseHeaderBag();
          $headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
          $headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="data.csv"');
          $headerArray = $headers->all();
          try {
           $response = new BinaryFileResponse($tempFile, 200, $headerArray, true);
          }catch(Exception $e) {
            \Drupal::logger('VBO')->notice($e->getMessage);
          }
          
    
          return $response;
    
        }
    }


What is the code snippet representing as pertaining to the Question? If that is your custom code, it doesn't contain valid PHP syntax. It can't work as written.

This is my custom code that extends views bulk operations that pertains to the question. I also tried VBO Export module with no code with the same results. Do you know what is wrong with my custom code above that extends views bulk operations? Drush cr is working okay and I don't get any errors in watchdog logs

I also don't get a WSOD.

Ah you mean the  fputcsv($out, array('Company Name'...)); section. I just abbreviated all the columns. I'll edit it so people don't get confused

Add clarifying information to the Question and explain what "doesn't seem to download" means, on a technical level. Using the network tab of the browser dev tools will probably show useful information about the failing request.

ok I'll go do that

You won't find any errors because there aren't any - executeMultiple is a void function, the response you're returning just isn't used for anything. It's possible to override the completion redirect (see https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/3042535 & https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/3207304), so in theory you could redirect to a route with a force-download, but it would leave your users on the batch page, rather than taking you back to the start. Weird UX. The standard solution for this in my experience is to save the file, and render a...

...message with a link to it on batch completion. Or you might be able to hack something with javascript/meta refresh tags on the completion page to redirect to a route serving the force-download, but it'd be messy

Thanks @Clive! I went to https://www.drupal.org/project/vbo_export/issues/2925601 and there was a comment in there about revision metadata fields fouling this up, and I was using revision metadata fields. I made a test view page with VBO Export with regular content, and it works like you said. I'm going to consider the routes you suggested. Thanks again!

So I tested it with new revision metadata fields and it worked. I'm thinking that the same comment was referring to this same issue where the content has been in the database for awhile. I'll follow that issue.

Thanks to @clive, I was able to find the pertinent issue links. Based on the information I found, I just needed to create a new views table and VBO Export works.
EDIT:
I was also hiding the message box, so that is why I couldn't see VBO Export's link. I didn't think a link to download the file would appear there.
